# in Safari jPlayer: ended event is not fired after second time setMedia

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, jplayer

I'm using the jQuery jPlayer to play video files. When the ended event fires I set a new video with the function 'setMedia'. In Safari this ended event only fires once. In other posts I read a solution to use the pause event, this doesn't work: after setting setMedia in the ended event, no events are fired in Safari (5.1), so no ended and no pause events are being fired.

Code sample:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
        console.log("Ready");
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            m4v: "videos/main-intro.m4v"
        });
    },pause: function () {
        console.log('Video Player Paused');
    }
    ,ended: function () {
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", { 
            m4v: "videos/outro-slide-1.m4v"
        });     
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play");
        console.log("Video player Ended");      
    }
});
```

In **Chrome** it workes fine, the console logs:

- Ready
- Video Player Paused
- Video player Ended
- Video Player Paused
- Video player Ended
- Etc..

In **Safari** it doesn't fire any events after the setMedia, it only logs:

- Ready

When I remove the setMedia function in the ended handler the events are triggered correctly.

update: However, on the iPad it seems to work randomly. It doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: i scrapped my answer, was useless.. any chance you could paste the offending code into a Fiddle so we can test/debug?

Comment: seen this? https://github.com/happyworm/jPlayer/issues/71

Comment: I'll look into that and will update on this asap

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a strange bug in Safari's HTML5 video tag implementation. It can be reproduced on Safari for Windows as well. I've just found one workaround for this problem - just bind to `loadedmetadata` event and set the `currentTime` to some non-zero value. Here is an example (don't forget to optimize it for jPlayer):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<video id="video" width="500" height="400" controls autoplay></video>
<script>
var src = [
 "http://content.adfox.ru/131007/adfox/205544/865991_11.mp4",
 "http://all.rutube.ru/130627/gpmdigital/217059/805529_11.mp4"
];
var curSrc = 0;
$(function() {
 $('#video').attr("src", src[curSrc % src.length]);
 curSrc++;
 var video = $('#video').get(0);

 $('#video')
 .on('loadedmetadata', function() {
  video.currentTime=0.01;
  video.play();
 })
 .on('ended', function() {
  console.log('ended');
  video.src = src[curSrc % src.length];
  video.load();
  curSrc++;
 });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can try this demo in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j2knz6sv/